# Cannot implicitly convert type to System.Collections.Generic.List to System.DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net, webapi

I need to add 2 columns(LastTaskCreatedDate & LastTaskUpdatedDate) for a table. I have the query for that 2coulums and I just need to call that query into my repo function.
My repo function already has a query inside it which get the other columns inside it. As i cant add another query inside, I creayed a function in it and added that query inside it.
Please look into the Screenshots for better clarity.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSMIZ.png)pic- The query which gets those two columns inside.

This is the repo funtion which gets the table data inside that and here i need to add those 2 columns also

```
        public WebStationResponse Filter(ProjectsFilter objFilter)
        {
            try
            {
                // Taking common project ids
                var projectIds = _currentUser.AccessInfo.UserProjects.Select(up => up.ProjectID).ToList();
                if (objFilter.ProjectID == null || objFilter.ProjectID.Count == 0)
                {
                    objFilter.ProjectID = projectIds;
                }
                objFilter.ProjectID = objFilter.ProjectID.Intersect(projectIds).ToList();
                objFilter.SetSqlPagingValues();
                objFilter.CompanyID = _currentUser.AccessInfo.CompanyID;
                objFilter.UserID = _currentUser.AccessInfo.UserID;
                objFilter.ServerTimezone = DefaultRepository.ServerTimezoneOffset();
                objFilter.UserTimezone = _currentUser.TimeZoneDetails.BaseUTCOffset;

                string strQuery = Project.GetProjects(objFilter);
                IList<ProjectDetails> lstProjectDetails = _dbContext.Database.Query<ProjectDetails>(strQuery,objFilter).ToList();
                if (lstProjectDetails.Count == 0)
                {
                    base.ResponseObject.ResponseId = (int)ResponseCode.RecordDoesnotExist;
                    return base.ResponseObject;
                }
                //
                int intRecordCount = lstProjectDetails.Count;
                if(objFilter.Pagination)
                {
                    intRecordCount = _dbContext.Database.ExecuteScalar<int>(Common.RecordCount());
                }
                FillPermissions(ref lstProjectDetails);
                FillProjectCompetencies(ref lstProjectDetails);
                **FillLastDates(ref lstProjectDetails); **
                base.FillResponseDetails(null,lstProjectDetails,null);
                base.ResponseObject.RecordCount = intRecordCount;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                base.FillResponseDetails(ex, null, null);
            }
            return base.ResponseObject;
        }`your text`
```

This is the function I added and inside it has the query- GetLastTaskUpdateDates.

```
        private void FillLastDates(ref IList<ProjectDetails> lstProjects)
        {
            if (lstProjects == null || lstProjects.Count == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            //
            var projectIds = lstProjects.Select(p => p.ProjectID).ToList();
            string strQuery = Project.GetLastTaskUpdatedDates();
            IList<ProjectDetails> lstDates = _dbContext.Database.Query<ProjectDetails>(strQuery, new { ProjectID = projectIds }).ToList();
            //
            ProjectDetails objProject = null;
            for (int intIndex = 0; intIndex < lstProjects.Count; intIndex++)
            {
                objProject = lstProjects[intIndex];
                lstProjects[intIndex].LastTaskCreated = lstDates.Where(c => c.ProjectID == objProject.ProjectID).ToList();
                lstProjects[intIndex].LastTaskUpdated= lstDates.Where(c =>c.ProjectID == objProject.ProjectID).ToList();

            }
        }`your text`
```

If we look at last two lines, I am getting this error- Cannot implicitly convert type to System.Collections.Generic.List to System.DateTime

Need help!!, Please reply for any other clarity on the problem

Gave everything in the details of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LastTaskCreate` and `LastTaskUpdated` are DateTime and you try to put lists instead of DateTimes, it's normal.

You must get only one date from the list you have. I think what you're looking for is something like that (assuming that lstDates is a list of dates):

```
var projectDates = lstDates.Where(c => c.ProjectID == objProject.ProjectID).OrderBy(e => e); // Ordered IEnumerable (it's a list but a bit different) of dates from the oldest to the newest
lstProjects[intIndex].LastTaskCreated = projectDates.First(); // Gives the first elem of the enumerable, should be the date of creation
lstProjects[intIndex].LastTaskUpdated = projectDates.Last(); // Gives the last elem of the enumerable, should be the last update date
```

I didn't put the null checkers but you might want to add some to be sure that projectDates is not empty.

If lstDates is a list of projects, the code could be this:

```
var project = lstDates.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ProjectID == objProject.ProjectID);

if (project != null)
{
    lstProjects[intIndex].LastTaskCreated = project.LastTaskCreated 
    lstProjects[intIndex].LastTaskUpdated = project.LastTaskUpdated 
}
```

but it depends on what's inside ProjectDetails.

Hope it helped

Comment: var project = lstDates.Where(c => c.ProjectID == objProject.ProjectID).FirstOrDefault();

if (project != null)
{
    lstProjects[intIndex].LastTaskCreated = project.LastTaskCreated 
    lstProjects[intIndex].LastTaskUpdated = project.LastTaskUpdated 
}


Tried this, its working.
But I am not getting the dates which are from database. Getting Default dates
            "LastTaskCreated": "0001-01-01 00:00:00",
            "LastTaskUpdated": "0001-01-01 00:00:00", like this

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't fully understand what's going on in your scenario, the error seems to be fairly explainatory?

```
lstProjects[intIndex].LastTaskCreated
```

expects a Datetime, whereas

```
lstDates.Where(c => c.ProjectID == objProject.ProjectID).ToList();
```

is a list of ProjectDetails.

I suspect you want something like:

```
lstProjects[intIndex].LastTaskCreated = lstDates.First(c => c.ProjectID == objProject.ProjectID).LastTaskCreated;
```